# SQLite deleted data stays in database binary file

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, security

I deleted data from SQLite database table. If you open the database file in any SQL manager (e.g SQLiteStudio) deleted data is not present, but if you open database file in a text editor (e.g notepad++) deleted data is visible. Therefore there's a chance of restoring data, etc.

Example:

*In the first picture SQLiteStudio is showing that deleted customer "Stan" is not seen. But binary file opened in Notepad++ shows customer "Stan".*

Does anybody know how to make deleted data disappear from SQLite binary files?

[image: SQLiteStudio showing that deleted customer "Stan" is not seen]

[image: Binary file open in Notepad++ shows customer "Stan"]

Answer (score 4):

To prevent this, execute [PRAGMA secure_delete = ON](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_secure_delete):

> When secure_delete is on, SQLite overwrites deleted content with zeros. The default setting for secure_delete is determined by the [SQLITE_SECURE_DELETE](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#secure_delete) compile-time option and is normally off. The off setting for secure_delete improves performance by reducing the amount of disk I/O. Applications that wish to avoid leaving forensic traces after content is deleted or updated should enable the secure_delete pragma prior to performing the delete or update, or else run [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) after the delete or update.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I have the same problem - I delete data from a table, run vacuum and even did the PRAGMA secure_delete=ON, but when I disconnect and close my SQLite editor, the -wal and -shm files remain, and when I delete them, my data is returned to the table if I open the database again. How do I get the data to be deleted in the database permanently? I need to copy this database to a mobile device, but I cannot get the data deleted

Comment: @Thys That would be anew question. But read the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) first.

Answer (score 3):

It is a normal behaviour for most databases. SQLite is not an exception. Most of the time the designers prefer speed vs the fragmentation.

To make the data completely disappear from your file you need to [vacuum](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) your database.

You can build your database with the [pragma auto_vacuum=FULL](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum) option to make it vacuum the database itself.